# Laravel Dynamic Dropdown get data from column in single table laravel

Tags: laravel

I try to get data from hour column by selected date from date column in singe table, but it doesn't work.
Please help.

Comment: you need to share your code, error (if happened)

Comment: Share some code that you have tried

Answer (score 0):

like the bellow code you have to work:

In your controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\{Country, State};

class HomeController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        return view('home', [
            'countries' => Country::all(),
            'states' => State::all(),
        ]);
    }
}
```

Put it in your blade file

```
<select name="country">
    @foreach ($countries as $country)
        <option value="{{ $country->id }}">{{ $country->name }}</option>
    @endforeach
</select>

<select name=“state”>
    @foreach ($states as $state)
        <option value="{{ $state->id }}">{{ $state->name }}</option>
    @endforeach
</select>
```